# Load image in a movieclip inside a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

for some strange reasons I'm here to develop a desktop app in as3, and I am really rusty on it.
I can not remember how to load an image inside a slider that contains 6 thumbs.
This thumbs are movieclips (named icon1, icon2, icon3...etc) that contains a transparent button and an empty movieclip (named image) that should contains the image.
This image have to be loaded dynamically.
The following is the code I did:

```
var count = 1;

for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest('img/img'+i+'.jpg');
    var loader: Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onImageLoadError);
    loader.load(request);
    count++;
}

function onImageLoadComplete(e: Event): void {
    trace('onImageLoadComplete()');
    var loaderInfo: LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.target);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onImageLoadError);

    var bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap(loaderInfo.content);
    slider["icon" + count]["image"].addChild(bitmap); ///at this line there's the error 
}

function onImageLoadError(e: IOErrorEvent): void {
    trace('onImageLoadError(): ' + e.text);
    var loaderInfo: LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.target);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onImageLoadError);
}
```

but no way, doesn't work the error is: Error #1010:A term is undefined and has no properties.
I tried also:

1)

```
slider["icon" + count].image.addChild(bitmap);
```

2)

```
var mc:MovieClip = ("icon"+ cont)as MovieClip;
slider.mc.image.addChild(bitmap);
```

please, if someone still remember as3 help me!

Comment: The problem is: after the first loop is complete, the **count** variable is **7**. So, whatever you do there after, you always address **"icon7"** object which just does not exist, hence, errors.

Comment: I advise to put the **Loader** instances into your slider thing directly in the first loop. You won't benefit from extracting these bitmaps in any reasonable way.

Comment: thank you @Organis but this isn't the problem, because if I change the bound to 6 I get the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @Organis's answer, that put me in the right direction, I changed the place where the count was incremented, and now it works. 
This is the right code:

```
var count = 1;

for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest('img/img'+i+'.jpg');
    var loader: Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onImageLoadError);
    loader.load(request);

}

function onImageLoadComplete(e: Event): void {
    trace('onImageLoadComplete()');
    var loaderInfo: LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.target);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onImageLoadError);

    var bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap(loaderInfo.content);
    slider["icon" + count]["image"].addChild(bitmap);
    count++;
}

function onImageLoadError(e: IOErrorEvent): void {
    trace('onImageLoadError(): ' + e.text);
    var loaderInfo: LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.target);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoadComplete);
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onImageLoadError);
}
```